# Generalized power rule for derivatives

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation

**Background**

This background is not really necessary to answer my question, but I included it here to provide context.

This question has some programming aspects to it as well, but since my question is mainly about math, I decided to ask it here.

I'm trying to extend the implementation of automatic differentiation found [here](http://conal.net/papers/beautiful-differentiation/beautiful-differentiation-jfp.pdf). This implementation, assuming I read it properly, does not work for functions of the form $F(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$. I'm trying to modify it so that it does work for such functions.

**Question**

I'm trying to find a derivative for functions of the form $F(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$. I specifically only care about the "normal" cases where $g(x)$ is an integral constant, or $f(x)$ is positive. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Generalized_power_rule) has provided me with a "Generalized Power Rule":

$$(f^g)^\prime = f^g\left(f^\prime\frac{g}{f}+g^\prime\ln f\right)$$

The generalized rule however does not work for $f\leq 0$. In my implementation it is difficult to tell which of the two cases I'm working with, so I would rather not need to implement this generalized rule for the latter case, and the basic power rule for the former.

Is there a rule that works for both cases?

Comment: How do you define $(-1.234)^{4.567}$?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Note, however, that regarding the following remark "This rule however does not work for $f(x)≤0$", it's true that it doesn't work but it's not only because the formula doesn't hold, it's much more than, it doesn't work because if $f(x)\leq 0$, then $f^g$ isn't even defined. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Hagen I don't understand the question. It looks like you have defined it there. That is one of the cases I don't care about.

Comment: @I have not defined it, I just wrote down the expression. By writing "How do you define $\frac00$?" I wouldn't suddenly produce a definition of $\frac00$ either.

Comment: @Hagen Well, I'm talking about derivatives, so if you have defined $f(x)=-1.234$ and $g(x)=4.567$ where $F(x)=f^g$ then $F^\prime(x)=0$

Comment: @Matt before claiming to know a value for the derivative $F'(0)$, could you say what the function value $F(0)$ is in the first place? - If you prefer nonconstant stuff, for which $x$ is  $F(x)=(x-1.234)^{4.567+x}$ defined?

Comment: It seems like people are having issues with exponentiation of negative numbers. I'm not really sure how those are usually evaluated, but I can tell you what some of them are. For example: $(-5)^{1/2}=5i$ Other than that, I fear I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Also, I don't actually care about that case

Comment: Your question inidicates that you *do* care specifically about this case, i.e. $f(x)<0$ and $g(x)$ not constant.

Comment: @Hagen Hmm... I see the problem here. I don't actually care about that case, but I don't really have a good way to tell which case I'm dealing with. I was hoping that there would be some general rule, but I guess Ill have to figure out how to tell what case I'm in, as fgp said.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You're misreading the question. The function $x^2$ _is_ well-defined even if $x<0$, but the formula for the logarithmic derivative breaks down there. The OP wants a formula that can handle _all_ cases without breaking down for trivial cases like $x^2$.

Comment: @Matt There is a general rule, see my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is stemming from confusion of the logarithm rule $$\ln a^r=r\ln a$$ **This is only valid if we have $a>0$.** Otherwise it does not hold. For example, $\ln((-1)^2)=\ln 1=0$ whereas $2\ln(-1)$ is not defined over the reals.

Instead, we can write $$\ln a^r=r\ln |a|,\;\;\;a^r>0$$ So in your case, let $y=x^2$. Then $\ln y=2\ln|x|$ so $$\frac{y'}{y}={2\over x}\implies y'=\frac{2y}{x}=2x$$ as desired. This holds for all $x\ne 0$.

In general, let $y=f(x)^{g(x)}$ and suppose that $f(x)^{g(x)}>0$ is defined and positive for all relevant $x$. Then we have $$\ln y=g(x)\ln |f(x)|,\;\;\;\frac{y'}{y}=g'\ln|f(x)|+g\frac{f'}{f}$$ so that

$$(f^g)'=f^g\left(g'\ln|f|+f'\frac{g}{f}\right)$$ We must have $f(x)\ne 0$ as expected.

**NOTE:** If a function satisfies the requirement that $f^g\ge 0$ for all $x$ in the domain, then at an anomalous point where f(x)=0 (such as the origin on the parabola $y=x^2$) the derivative there must be $0$ because it will be a minimum of the function (assuming it is differentiable at all).

Comment: $a^r$ is not defined if e.g. $a = -1$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$. Since undefined functions generally don't have derivatives, how does that help?

Comment: @fgp I specified that $a^r>0$ was the necessary assumption. That means it is defined and strictly positive.

Comment: I also said "suppose $f^g>0$" in the middle of the post. Thanks though, edited accordingly. And I don't think undefined functions _ever_ have derivatives... :)

Comment: What does $a^r > 0$ *mean*? What's your definition of $a^r$, if not $a^r = e^{r\ln a}$, which of course presumes that $a > 0$?

Comment: Your **NOTE** isn't true. $\sqrt{x}$ is non-negative on it's domain $[0,\infty)$, yet the derivative at $0$ isn't zero. It does, in fact, not exist. (or is $\infty$, depending on whether you allow that case. Allowing that makes sense here, actually, because $\sqrt{x}$ *does* have a tangent at $x=$ - the tangest is simply the $y$-axis)

Comment: @fgp $a^r>0$ means $a^r>0$! What is confusing? For example, $x^2>0$ for all $x\ne 0$ even though the function $x$ is not always positive. As to your counterexample $\sqrt x$, I said "assuming it is differentiable at all". In other words, either it's differentiable and zero or not differentiable.

Comment: But knowing that $f'$ is either zero or doesn't exist isn't very helpfull if one wants to write an algorithm that differentiates.... Also, *the whole point* is that $a^r$ means zilch, zero, nada, nothing if $a < 0$. Saying "if $a^r > 0$ ... " presume that $a^r$ exists in the first place!

Comment: Let $a<0$. Then $a^2$ does _not_ mean zilch. It means $a^2$. Or again, $$(a^2)^a$$ is well-defined. We cannot simplify it to $a^{2a}$, but if we use absolute values judiciously we can still apply logarithmic differentiation as I have explained in the post.

Comment: @fgp Note that the OP wants to create a differentiation algorithm which will recursively simplify derivatives of the form $f^g$ into more basic derivatives using the general power-rule formula. The point here is not to get picky over anomalous cases - the OP simply needs a formula that's valid for basic cases like $x^2$ even when $x<0$.

Comment: @NotNotLogical This is correct. Ill update the question to make that more clear

Comment: @NotNotLogical Yup, and I'm saying that getting the "generalized" power law to correctly return $0$ for the derivative of $x^n$ at $0$ but $\infty$ (or NaN or error or whatever) for the derivative of $\sqrt[n]{x}$ at $0$ is not trivial. And those are *not* anomalous cases! Heck, they don't even *need* the "generalized" power law, because the exponent is constant anyway. The problem here is that this "generalized" law makes *way* to many assumptions, and *isn't* a true generalization of $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$. As witnessed by the fact that it get into serious trouble for $x=0$.

Comment: @fgp I pointed that out clearly in my post. I don't disagree with anything you're saying, nor does it contradict what was claimed in my answer. I acknowledged the difficulties, and hopefully someone can find a better solution :)

Comment: @fgp You may be interested in this question I just posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773578/derivative-of-fxgx-at-points-when-fx-0

Comment: Other than for $f=0$, are there well defined functions $f(x)^{g(x)}$ for which your modified general rule doesn't work?

Comment: @Matt I believe at points where $f(x)\ne 0$ and $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is defined, the formula will always return the correct answer. I recommend that you experiment with some different functions to confirm this though. BTW, I would love to hear how your differentiation program goes! I have been wanting to program a simple CAS myself for quite some time, but I've never been able to figure out how I would make it... I'm much stronger in math than in programming :) Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You have two conflicting goals here. If $y$ is *arbitrary*, then $x^y$ only
makes sense for $x>0$. Imagine, for example, that $y = \frac{1}{2}$.
Then $x^y = \sqrt{x}$ - what does that mean for negative $x$?

Note that switching to complex numbers doesn't help much - negative numbers do have
square roots then, but those are *non-unique*, and what's worse, the number
of solutions is highly dependent on $y$! E.g., $y^n = x$ has $n$ solutions in
$\mathbb{C}$. Which is $x^\frac{1}{n}$ supposed to be?

So you'll have to distinguish between two cases. One is $f(x)^{g(x)}$ for
positive $f$, and the other is $f(x)^k$ for *constants* $k \in \mathbb{Z}$
(i.e., no fractional exponents). You could generalize the second case to
$f(x)^{g(x)}$ for functions $g$ which take only integral values, but since
such functions are either constant or non-continuous, that case isn't really
interesting for purposes of differentiation, I think.

BTW, a far more interesting (and maybe solvable!) question is how to deal with
non-negative $f$, which nevertheless may take the value zero. $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is perfectly well-defined for those, but you'll still run into problems with the logarithm. Now, in *some* cases these problems are due to the fact that the derivative does, in fact, not exists at these points. But not in al cases! For example, $f(x) = x^2$ has derivative $0$ at $x=0$. The reason is, basically, that since $g$ is constant in this case, then  $g' ln f$ doesn't matter, because $g' = 0$, and similarly for $f'\frac{g}{f}$. But you can't just cancel things that way in *all* cases - that will produce wrong answers sometimes, because it actually depends on how *fast* things go to zero respectively infinity.

---

You might ask, then, why the non-uniqueness mentioned above doesn't prevent us from sensibly defining $\sqrt[x]{x}$ - after all, $y^n = x$ has *two* solutions for positive $x$ even in \mathbb{R}$. The reason is twofold

1. The number of solutions doesn't explode as badly. We have one solution of $y^n = x$ for odd $n$, and two for even $n$.
2. There's an *order* on $\mathbb{R}$, which makes the definition of $\sqrt[n]{x}$ as the (unique!) *positive* solution of $y^n = x$ quite natural.

The effect of (1) and (2) is, for example, that while it's *not* true that $\sqrt[n]{x^n} = x$, we do get at least that $\sqrt[n]{x^n} = |x|$. Trying to do the same over the complex numbers fails horribly. We could attempt to define $\sqrt[n]{x}$ as the solution of $y^n =x$ with the smallest *angle* (assuming we agree to measure angles counter-clockwise from the real axis). But then an $n$-th root always has an angle smaller than $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, so $\sqrt[n]{x^n}$ and $x$ would have very little in common except that their $n$-th power is $x^n$.

Comment: Aren't square roots already non-unique? i.e. $\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$?

Comment: @Matt No $\sqrt 4=+2$. But the equation $x^2=4$ has two solutions, $\pm\sqrt 4$ (i.e. $\pm 2$)

Comment: @Hagen Is that a useful distinction? What is the application of square root if not solving equations? Also, how is that different from the case outlined here, the way it is worded now is "E.g., $y^n=x$ has $n$ solutions in $\mathbb C$" (I'm pointing out the word "solutions" here)

Comment: @Matt I've added an explanation of why non-unique roots pose less of a problem in $\mathbb{R}$ compared to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Matt I've also added a section about the fact that not *strictly* positive $f$ already cause problems, even though there are no definedness issues there! I'd concentrate on those - unless you can find a way around these, using the generalized power law will cause trouble if applied to very simply expressions like $x^2$, if the result is evaluated at zero.